# how can i get the path plus the name of the first file in a folder and so on in python

Tags: python, python-os

I got this code and i need to take the first path of a file and the files name an have put it as a string

```
from pathlib import Path
from os import walk
import os
from posixpath import dirname
f = []
jhon = r'C:\Users\ioshu\Desktop\you'
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(jhon):
    f.extend(filenames)
    f.extend(dirnames)
    break
Ben1= filenames[:1]
Ben2= dirpath[:2]

dataFolder = Path(r'C:\Users\ioshu\Desktop\you')

print(Ben1 , dataFolder)
print(dataFolder)
```

The `print (ben1, dataFolder)`
the output" of that file is
`C:\Users\ioshu\Desktop\you ['07a5iya4vfm91-DASH_720.mp4']`
The problem is that i need the out put to be like this `C:\Users\ioshu\Desktop\you\0q74nqluycm91-DASH_720`

Comment: Please format the code properly in code blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `walk` will walk the whole tree, which is overkill for your needs. You can simply

```py
    first_file_name = os.listdir('/etc')[0]
```

if you are sure there are only files, or:

```
import os

path = '/etc'  # any path you want
first_file = None
for i in os.listdir(path):
    file_path = os.path.join(path, i)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        first_file = file_path
        break  # assuming you don't need to sort the names
```

Always use `os.path.join` to join paths, works on Linux, Windows, MacOS and any other supported platform.

PS: `Ben1 = filenames[:1]` returns a list with one element, not the element. If you need the element then: `Ben1 = filenames[0]`.

PS2: If you want to use `pathlib` then `dataFolder / filenames[0]` or something will help.